# Delphi RAD Studio Serial Number

Tags: delphi, license-key

We currently use **Rad Studio 2007** and are expecting to upgrade to Delphi XE soon!

Does anybody know how we can see what the **serial number** was used when installing Rad Studio 2007?

Regards, Pieter

Answer (score 24, accepted):

'LicenseManager.exe' in the 'bin' folder of the 'Rad Studio' installation should show it.

Answer (score 10):

Also, you can see all your registered products with serial numbers on EDN [My registered products](https://members.embarcadero.com/Products.aspx) page (after logging in).